# How to update a tkinter notebook tab on button click?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creatig a log-in system in a tkinter.notebook tab and I need to update the tab to enter the actual program after the user enters its userName and its password and click a button

Im using python 3.7 and the lastest tkinter version

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainApp(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        main_window.title("User")

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self,height=600,width=500)

        self.reservation_page=reservaiones(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.reservation_page,text="Reservations",padding=10)

        self.notebook.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.pack()

class reservaiones(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.userName=tk.Entry(self)
        self.userName.place(x=100,y=50)
        self.userNameLabel=tk.Label(self,text="User Name")
        self.userNameLabel.place(x=20, y =50)

        self.password= tk.Entry(self)
        self.password.place(x=100,y=100)
        self.userNameLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Password")
        self.userNameLabel.place(x=20, y=100)

        self.logIn=tk.Button(self,text="Log In",command=self.getLoginInfo)
        self.logIn.place(x=100,y=200)

    def getLoginInfo(self):
        userName=self.userName.get()
        password=self.password.get()
        # Change this for the actual user list
        logInList=[['1','a','0'],['2','b','1'],['3','c','0']]

        for user in logInList:
            if userName==user[0]:
                if password==user[1] and user[2]!='1':
                    continue
                elif password==user[1] and user[2]=='1':
                    self.migration=tk.Label(self,text="User with migration issues")
                    self.migration.place(x=50,y=150)
                else:
                    self.wrongUserPassword = tk.Label(self, text="Access denied, wrong User Name or Password")
                    self.wrongUserPassword.place(x=2, y=150)
            else:
                self.wrongUserPassword = tk.Label(self, text="Access denied, wrong User Name or Password")
                self.wrongUserPassword.place(x=2, y=150)
                break

        self.userName.delete(0,tk.END)
        self.password.delete(0,tk.END)
```

This is the tab so far, the idea is that when the user enters 1 as user-name and a as password the tab updates itself

Comment: There's no notebook tab in your code.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i forgot to include it, now there is :)

Comment: What do you mean by *I need to update the tab to enter the actual program*, do you have code for your *actual program*

Comment: Like when you login into Facebook, you enter your username and password and then click login and then it enters your account, I need to do that but in a notebook tab like showing other things once the login is complete

Comment: I see that your `MainApp` inherits from `Tk` but it also has a master. Are you using multiple instances of `Tk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change your method `getLoginInfo` to something like this:

```
def getLoginInfo(self):
    login_success=False
    userName=self.userName.get()
    password=self.password.get()
    # Change this for the actual user list
    logInList=[['1','a','0'],['2','b','1'],['3','c','0']]

    for user in logInList:
        if userName==user[0]:
            if password==user[1] and user[2]!='1':
                login_success=True
                break
            elif password==user[1] and user[2]=='1':
                self.migration=tk.Label(self,text="User with migration issues")
                self.migration.place(x=50,y=150)
            else:
                self.wrongUserPassword = tk.Label(self, text="Access denied, wrong User Name or Password")
                self.wrongUserPassword.place(x=2, y=150)
        else:
            self.wrongUserPassword = tk.Label(self, text="Access denied, wrong User Name or Password")
            self.wrongUserPassword.place(x=2, y=150)
            break
    if login_success:
        # Remove all the current widgets before drawing new
        for child in self.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
        self.call_next_function_to_draw_actual_program()
```

Comment: When i remove the widgets it throws me an error, it doesn't has any effect in the program, but, how can I solve this error?